# How to get equivalent label name for second smallest value in array Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the google maps API to obtain the nearest marker in a list of markers after dragging one across the map. Here is my code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend',
    function (markerFunc) {
        var latLng = markerFunc.latLng;
        marker.position = latLng;
        
        var smallest = Infinity;
        var secondSmallest = Infinity;
        var labelSecondSmallest="";
        
        for(var i=0; i<markers.length; i++){
          
        var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(marker.position, markers[i].position, 100);
        console.log("Distance from " + marker.label + " to " + markers[i].label + " is" + distance);

            if (distance < smallest) {
                secondSmallest = smallest;
                smallest = distance;
            } else if (distance < secondSmallest) {
                secondSmallest = distance;
                labelSecondSmallest = markers[i].label
            }


        }
        
        console.log(secondSmallest);
        console.log(labelSecondSmallest);

    }
);
```

My output looks like the following:
[image]

Here you can see in the example the second smallest value is V2 to D2 and the float value is printed out below. However, the string `D1` is being printed out as opposed to `D2` which is the correct answer. How can I return the intended string?

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pw23vbLm/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are not storing the label for the smallest value, so when the smallest value becomes the second smallest value, there's no label to go with it.  Add in a labelSmallest variable and keep track of that as well as the distance.  Something like:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend',
function (markerFunc) {
    var latLng = markerFunc.latLng;
    marker.position = latLng;
    
    var smallest = Infinity;
    var secondSmallest = Infinity;
    var labelSmallest = "";
    var labelSecondSmallest="";
    
    for(var i=0; i<markers.length; i++){
      
    var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(marker.position, markers[i].position, 100);
    console.log("Distance from " + marker.label + " to " + markers[i].label + " is" + distance);
        if (distance < smallest) {
            secondSmallest = smallest;
            labelSecondSmallest = labelSmallest;
            smallest = distance;
            labelSmallest = markers[i].label;
        } else if (distance < secondSmallest) {
            secondSmallest = distance;
            labelSecondSmallest = markers[i].label;
        }
    }
    
    console.log(secondSmallest);
    console.log(labelSecondSmallest);

    }
);
```

Comment: You got it earlier. I will give you credit for this. Will remove my answer. Nice one.

Comment: It works thanks. Just to let you know ```labelSmallest = marker[i].label``` should be ```labelSmallest = markers[i].label```

Comment: Thanks - I've updated the code as suggested just to make it clearer for anyone else reading this